# Android display to TV?

Tags: hdmi, external-display

I have an android device(tablet) and I want the screen that I see on my tablet to be able to see it on my TV. The TV has HDMI to which I connected but I only have the video playback or whatever. I need what I see on my tablet to be able to also see on the TV. I need this very fast. Any help is appreciated.

I understand it is possible but only for movies. Is there a way to see media other than movies?

Comment: Which tablet do you have? Plugging my Xoom into HDMI always mirrors what's on the screen.

Comment: I have 7 different tablet types(ranging from an lg phone with android 2.2.2 to iconia tab t500 android 3.2) and I need them all to work which they don't. So I'm thinking there is an options or a feature that you have to enable on the tablet for it to work.

Comment: It's also possible it just isn't supported. The HTC EVO doesn't do full mirroring without rooting and installing a custom app for it. This really depends on the device, I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

I have both the Iconia A500 and the Transformer TF101. Both output just fine to TVs with HDMI.

There is a little bit cropped off the image in both cases and the home - back - recent buttons don't show on the TVs, nor does the notification panel, all suggesting that it isn't really an external monitor type feature, only to play back movies etc on the big screens.